# Call async over sync c# without thread locking

Tags: c#, async-await

I have made a lightweight mediator kind of library for use internally.

A query can be mapped to a async method without the caller knowing anything about it.

```cs
public interface IMediator
    {
        TResult ExecuteQuery<TResult>(Query<TResult> query);
        Task<TResult> ExecuteQueryAsync<TResult>(Query<TResult> query);
    
        Task ExecuteCommandAsync(Command command);
        Task<TResult> ExecuteCommandAsync<TResult>(Command<TResult> command);
        
        void ExecuteCommand(Command command);
        TResult ExecuteCommand<TResult>(Command<TResult> command);

        void EnqueueTask(object task);
    }

 public abstract class Query<TResult> { }

 public interface IQueryHandler<Query, TResult> where Query : Query<TResult>
    {

        TResult Handle(Query param);
    }

    public interface IAsyncQueryHandler<Query, TResult> where Query : Query<TResult>
    {
        Task<TResult> Handle(Query param);
    }
```

When the caller is in a sync thread e.g factory method in the service container and want to execute a query it can not do that async using the `ExecuteQueryAsync` but the actual handler of the query, implementing the `IAsyncQueryHandler` is async.

So I need to call async over sync.

I do some reflection a registration time to actually figure out how to call the handler,
I tried the .wait() and .result() but I get thread locks.

current code looks like this.

```cs
private object AsyncSync(object service, object param)
{
  dynamic t = Method.Invoke(service, new[] { param });
  return t.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

The `Method` is the method info from reflection, and the `service` is an instance of the class with that method.

This code still gives me deadlock of threads.

How could I achieve this with, do I need to look into the task factory? Any suggestions?

Comment: Note: this isn't "async over sync", it is "sync over async" - and the only valid answer is: "don't do that"; if you want to consume an awaitable: *be async yourself*; there is no workaround that makes it OK to do this

Comment: If you need a sync API, provide one that actually is. It'll be probably faster to finish and more stable, even if it means to do the same thing in two different ways.

Comment: You are mentioning that you need to call async methods inside your "factory method in the service container." This is an absolute no-go, because object resolution should be fast and reliable (read [this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) and [this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/)). Async calls are slow and do I/O and are therefore unreliable.

Comment: Yes I agree on that, and probably could have figured out a way to achieve that.  But in this particular case I need to get some data from the database. In the start of a request. But apart from that I agree :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As as been commented already, the optimal solution would be to have `async` all the way... but sometimes that's not possible. Even Microsoft has acknowledged this by having a tool in their own frameworks to run `async` methods synchronously:

```
public static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory MyTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
    {
        var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        return MyTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
            return func();
        }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        MyTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
            return func();
        }).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs

You use it like this:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    await DoSomethingElseAsync();
    return 0;
}

int result = AsyncHelper.RunSync(async () => await DoSomethingAsync());
```

My feeling about this is that if Microsoft does this in their own frameworks, then it's OK for us to do the same.

Comment: Dumb question. Is there any issue with doing `AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => DoSomethingAsync());`? (no `async` and `await` keyword in the `RunSync()`)

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to GTHvidsten
This is the solution that seems to be working.

```cs
private object RunTaskTSync(Func<Task<object>> task)
{
    var cultureUi = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    return _taskFactory
        .StartNew(()=> {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUi;
            return task(); })
        .Unwrap()
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();
}

private object AsyncSync(object service, object param)
{
    return RunTaskTSync(async () => await (dynamic)Method.Invoke(service, new[] { param }));
}
```

I do not like the dynamic thing, but it is an easy way to do it :)

Comment: Just because it works, doesn't mean that you should throw away type information and add runtime overhead like that. Your mediator would only need an implementation of `IQueryHandler` which calls `RunSync<TResult>` for any `IAsyncQueryHandler` (and vice versa). No reflection should be required.